# How to debug 100% cpu - python subprocess

Tags: debugging

While I am working with nvim, I get occasion periods of 100% cpu stems mostly from the Python subprocess of nvim (some other times it is node). It happens when I do nothing in vim.

I tried to do profiling of vim functions, but nothing came up.

Apperently, the python plugins are: coc-python, leaderF, vim-netranger, ycm(disabled prob), vimspector. 
They are ordered by likelihood from the most likely to the least.

Is there a good way to debug this?

Comment: you may have answers if you disclose which python plugins you are using

Comment: I will examine more carefully the open files and ports in activity monitor.

Comment: @eyalkarni please edit your question to include these information, it's easier to spot than in the comments

Comment: Are there autocommands setup on CursorHold?

Comment: coc_nvim  ,
gitgutter  ,
ALEEvents,  
auto_save , 
gitgutter,  
airline_ale

Comment: It could be a timer too. Only coc is relevant here in terms of python.

Comment: Just updating that I encounter it again: it is run by script_host.py of nvim, no relevant open files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use that vimspector you have installed (in another instance of vim) to attach to the python process and get a stack trace.

Debugpy supports attach-by-PID so you do something like [this](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy#attaching-to-a-running-process-by-id):

```
python -m debugpy --listen localhost:5678 --pid <pid of the spinning process>
```

Then use vimspector to attach to it, using the [simple remote-attach config](https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector#remote-debugging-1).

You should then be able to see what it's doing; from the stack trace you could at least identify the errant plugin and report to the maintainer. I hope it's not one of mine ;)

Of course, you could also use pdb or something :)